# error: modules are not supported in -source 8 - Intellij Idea

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, java-11

I am using jdk 11.0.6 and gradle alone with javaFX plugin. When running the program, intellij gives me the error

```
4:46:44 PM: Executing task 'run'...

> Configure project :
Found module name 'Notes'

> Task :compileJava FAILED
C:\Users\fahid\IdeaProjects\Notes\src\main\java\module-info.java:1: error: modules are not supported in -source 8
module Notes {
^
  (use -source 9 or higher to enable modules)
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
4:46:45 PM: Task execution finished 'run'.
```

[image: ScreenShot -1]
[image: Screenshot -2]

How can I fix it?

note- I have selected jdk 11 in both project structure and module section.(Screenshot).

Comment: the first error tells you all: wrong jdk in setup ..

Comment: The IDE is set up correctly, but your Gradle build is not configured for Java 9+ features.

Comment: @JoachimSauer If it works like Maven, IntelliJ's setup is driven by the Gradle config.